# Sending GET data to a url from a database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

`EDIT:` I want to load the page for each gamertag, so that it creates the images.

`EDIT 2:` Here is new script I have, if it were working correctly the the [page](http://www.halogamertags.com/tags) would have more than 2 images on it

```
<?php
require_once('sql.php');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gamertags");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    // Prepare gamertag for url
    $gamertag = strtolower($row['gamertag']);
    //echo $gamertag.'<br />';
    $url = "http://halogamertags.com/tags/index.php?player_name=".urlencode($gamertag);
    $get_result = file_get_contents($url);
}
?>
```

Comment: You know how to get the gamertags?
SELECT * FROM gamertags!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!? Hmmm.... If you know the gamertag why not select only the record of that particular gamertag? Right now you're selecting ALL records of ALL gamertags and processing each... I think you need to do some more research on development...

Comment: See my edit - I think I understand you better now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$tag_encoded = urlencode($gamertag);

$url = "http://halogamertags.com/tags/index.php?player_name=$tag_encoded";

// To request the page's content
$html = file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: I would not use the index.php but instead do this:
$url = "http:// halogamertags.com/tags/?player_name=$tag_encoded";

Comment: I want it to load that page FOR EACH GAMERTAG so it runs it's scripts and creates the images, which is about 980,000

Answer (score 0):

Checked the URL you provided, it's a link to a page that has a bunch of image templates you can use. I chose one and went with it:

```
<?php
require_once('sql.php');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gamertags");

$images = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

    $gamertag = $row['gamertag'];

    // assuming this URL is just an image
    $url = "http://halogamertags.com/tags/sig2.php?player=".urlencode($gamertag);

    $images []= $url;
}

foreach ($images as $img)
{
    echo '<img src="'.$img.'"><br />';
}
```

Comment: What part of "I know how to get the gamertags I just need help forming the url..." makes you think that?

Comment: "Where the player_name will be equal to a gamertag"

Comment: @Sani The `player_name` is the GET param; what is your interpretation of the question?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's referring to the URL specification, not a condition on the query.

Comment: I do understand what he/she really wants to know but that doesn't make the question more correct does it? "player_name" is not the variable in this case but the OQ says it is... this is wrong...

Comment: @Jimmy I want it to load that page FOR EACH GAMERTAG so it runs it's scripts and creates the images, which is about 980,000

Comment: @Andrew the code of any of the three answers here should load that page fine, just throw it in the body of that loop and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Andrew also, instead of the `str_replace` call you run, simply run a `urlencode` on the gamertag and that'll take care of spaces as well as all other illegal characters.

Comment: @Sani I think your comment is still irrelevant; the OP simply didn't understand this code should be placed in the body of the `foreach`.

Comment: the problem here is that everyone thinks that the replacing should be: player_name=*to be replaced** but the reality is that *to be replaced*=xxx is what is asked...

Comment: @Sani Why would the OP then use `str_replace()` with `%20` which then appears in the value of the GET param in their example? Also, why would anyone sane use that method of specifying a gamer tag, which makes it non trivial to extract?

Comment: @alex: I might be wrong... and if I am I'll admit it but the Q is not clear... nor is the comments from the OP...

Comment: @Sani I initially thought that too but that wouldn't make a whole lot of sense, so I assumed what I wrote is what he meant. If not, it should be a fairly trivial fix to change it.

Comment: @alex and @Jimmy Sawczuk: It sure don't make sense... Well... After all your comments and after the edit and more thinking about the problem I must agree with @alex... (Still no -1 :) )

Comment: @Andrew another edit, that should do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In case it wasn't obvious, this code should be placed at the end of your `foreach` block.

You should also skip the `str_replace()` and just use `urlencode()` as per the example below.

```
file_get_contents(
 'http://halogamertags.com/tags/index.php?player_name=' . urlencode($gamertag)
);
```

Assuming `allow_url_fopen` is on in your `php.ini`.

Otherwise, use a library such as cURL.

#### Update

> Here is new script I have, if it were working correctly the the page would have more than 2 images on it

You only have two `img` elements there. You need to provide much more information and code.

Comment: @Sani Care to explain further?

Comment: @alex I want it to load that page FOR EACH GAMERTAG so it runs it's scripts and creates the images, which is about 980,000

Comment: @Andrew Place this code in the body of your loop. That should be obvious.

Comment: when you go to that page and submit a gamertag in the form it creates images which are displayed and saved to a folder, if you go back to the original page it will pull all of the images from the folder an put them on the page.

Comment: @Andrew There a lot of places of failure there of which you haven't posted code for.